# how to set the index page in django like http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Tags: python, django

I have created a small project like this structure..

```
|-mysite

   |-polls

   |---static

   |-----polls

   |-------css

   |---------images

   |-------images

   |-------js

   |---templates

   |-----polls

   |-templates

   |---admin
```

Here In polls is the app and now i am getting output with this url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/`
In main folder i.e mysite folder in urls.py i have code like this..

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/',include('polls.urls',namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Now in polls folder in urls.py code is..

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$',views.index, name = 'index'),
}
```

Now i want to get the page like main website address like.. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`
How to get?
Thanks.

Comment: Whats your observation when u tried to run it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change what you have here

```
url(r'^polls/',include('polls.urls',namespace="polls")),
```

to

```
url(r'^', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
```

Now the reason is this:
Django urls uses regex. In your example, you're telling django to catch your polls app, beginning from the url as localhost:8000/polls/

Learn more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

Even in your root project urls.py, you've got this:

```
# Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'Toolkit.views.home', name='home'), #this will match url of the type localhost:8000
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')), # this will match url of the type localhost:8000/blog/
```

Just look sharp!

Comment: Yes thanks i forgot totally about main urls.py and blindly followed tutorial.